# How to create a layout as shown in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, layout, grid

I am new to R

I want to create a layout using grid library in R as show below.

How can I do it?

My sample code:

```
  library(grid)
  library(gridBase)

  grid.newpage()
  ly = grid.layout(3, 3)
  grid.show.layout(ly)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with `grid.arrange()` from the `gridExtra`-library.
They have a good vignette detailing the process [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/vignettes/Ecosystem.html), but in essence you create a matrix detailing your layout, like this:

```
grid.arrange(
  grobs = gl,
  widths = c(2, 1, 1),
  layout_matrix = rbind(c(1, 2, NA),
                        c(3, 3, 4))
)
```

This allows for great flexibility, but it can be a hassle to work out the exact matrix by hand.